# Drop data frame columns by name

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

I have a number of columns that I would like to remove from a data frame. I know that we can delete them individually using something like:

```
df$x <- NULL
```

But I was hoping to do this with fewer commands.

Also, I know that I could drop columns using integer indexing like this:

```
df <- df[ -c(1, 3:6, 12) ]
```

But I am concerned that the relative position of my variables may change.

Given how powerful R is, I figured there might be a better way than dropping each column one by one.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why R doesn't have something simple like `df#drop(var_name)`, and instead, we need to do these complicated work-arounds?

Comment: @ifly6 The 'subset()' function in R is about as parsimonious as the 'drop()' function in Python, except you don't need to specify the axis argument...  I agree that it's annoying that there can't be just one, ultimate, easy keyword/syntax implemented across the board for something so basic as dropping a column.

Answer (score 537, accepted):

There's also the `subset` command, useful if you know which columns you want:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 2:11, c = 3:12)
df <- subset(df, select = c(a, c))
```

UPDATED after comment by @hadley: To *drop* columns a,c you could do:

```
df <- subset(df, select = -c(a, c))
```

Comment: I really wish the R `subset` function had an option like "allbut = FALSE", which "inverts" the selection when set to TRUE, i.e. retains all columns *except* those in the `select` list.

Comment: @prasad, see @joris answer below. A subset without any subset criteria is a bit of overkill. Try simply: `df[c("a", "c")]`

Comment: @JD I knew that, but I like the syntactic convenience of the `subset` command where you don't need to put quotes around the column names -- I guess I don't mind typing a few extra characters just to avoid quoting names :)

Comment: oh that's a good point. I hadn't thought about the quote issue.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `subset` inside other functions.

Comment: @mac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850141/programming-safe-version-of-subset-to-evaluate-its-condition-while-called-from/12852005#12852005

Comment: subset(df, select = -c(b)) @spacetyper

Comment: I was using this, but I am getting an error now: `Error: unexpected '=' in "DT <- subset(DT, select="` Did something change?

Comment: You need to pass an argument for `subset`. e.g.: df <- subset(df, subset = TRUE, select = -c(a, c))

Answer (score 1044):

You can use a simple list of names :

```
DF <- data.frame(
  x=1:10,
  y=10:1,
  z=rep(5,10),
  a=11:20
)
drops <- c("x","z")
DF[ , !(names(DF) %in% drops)]
```

Or, alternatively, you can make a list of those to keep and refer to them by name :

```
keeps <- c("y", "a")
DF[keeps]
```

EDIT :
For those still not acquainted with the `drop` argument of the indexing function, if you want to keep one column as a data frame, you do:

```
keeps <- "y"
DF[ , keeps, drop = FALSE]
```

`drop=TRUE` (or not mentioning it) will drop unnecessary dimensions, and hence return a vector with the values of column `y`.

Comment: the subset function works better as it won't convert a data frame with one column into a vector

Comment: @mut1na check the argument drop=FALSE of the indexing function.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `DF[,keeps]` instead of `DF[keeps]` ?

Comment: @lindelof No. It can, but then you have to add drop=FALSE to keep R from converting your data frame to a vector if you only select a single column. Don't forget that data frames are lists, so list selection (one-dimensional like I did) works perfectly well and always returns a list. Or a data frame in this case, which is why I prefer to use it.

Comment: @AjayOhri Yes, it would. Without a comma, you use the "list" way of selecting, which means that even when you extract a single column, you still get a data frame returned. If you use the "matrix" way, as you do, you should be aware that if you only select a single column, you get a vector instead of a data frame. To avoid that, you need to add drop=FALSE. As explained in my answer, and in the comment right above yours...

Comment: Why not use `DF[!(names(DF) %in% drops)]`? By what has been said in these comments, it should be equivalent to using `drop=FALSE`, which is probably what we want anyway.

Answer (score 260):

```
within(df, rm(x))
```

is probably easiest, or for multiple variables:

```
within(df, rm(x, y))
```

Or if you're dealing with `data.table`s (per [How do you delete a column by name in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9202413)):

```
dt[, x := NULL]   # Deletes column x by reference instantly.

dt[, !"x"]   # Selects all but x into a new data.table.
```

or for multiple variables

```
dt[, c("x","y") := NULL]

dt[, !c("x", "y")]
```

Comment: `within(df, rm(x))` is *by far* the cleanest solution. Given that this is a possibility, every other answer seems unnecessarily complicated by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Note that `within(df, rm(x))` will _not_ work if there are duplicate columns named `x` in `df`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico to clarify, it removes neither but seems to change the data's values. One has bigger problems if this is the case, but here's an example: `df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 2); names(df) <- c("x", "x"); within(df, rm(x))` returns `data.frame(x = 2, x = 2)`.

Comment: @MilesErickson Problem is that you rely on a function `within()` which is powerful but also uses NSE. The note on the help page states clearly that for programming sufficient care should be used.

Comment: @MilesErickson How often would one encounter a dataframe with duplicate names in it?

Comment: @HSchmale `df<-data.frame(x=1:3,y=4:6,x=7:9)` is valid, but the last column becomes `x.1`. I've only seen duplicate names in lists. To get it in a data frame, you need to pass the `check.names = FALSE` argument.

Comment: Two other major benefits of `within`: You do not need to pass a `drop=FALSE` argument and `rm` will warn you if the column that you are attempting to delete is missing. `[` is not so kind.

Comment: If column names are "weird", for example with spaces etc.  you can also use `within(DF,rm(list=c("x","z")))`

Answer (score 139):

You could use `%in%` like this:

```
df[, !(colnames(df) %in% c("x","bar","foo"))]
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this effectively the same solution as the first part of Joris' answer?  `DF[ , !(names(DF) %in% drops)]`

Comment: @DanielFletcher: it's the same. Look at the timestamps on the answers. We answered at the same time... 5 years ago. :)

Comment: Nutty.  `identical(post_time_1, post_time_2) [1] TRUE`  =D

Comment: Why not drop the comma? I see no reason why `df[!(colnames(df) %in% c("x","bar","foo"))]` would not be equivalent.

Comment: why does it return FALSE/TRUE vector when I run on data.table data frame. Why?

Comment: @J.Mini Kind of safety. `x[names(x)]` works on any object that has subsetting and defined names. `x[, colnames(x)]` works only on objects that have two dimensions and defined column names, which is typically just `data.frame` and `matrix`. If the object doesn't have two dimensions, it explicitly throws error.

Answer (score 67):

list(NULL) also works:

```
dat <- mtcars
colnames(dat)
# [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
# [11] "carb"
dat[,c("mpg","cyl","wt")] <- list(NULL)
colnames(dat)
# [1] "disp" "hp"   "drat" "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

Comment: Brilliant! This extends the NULL assignment to a single column in a natural way, and (seemingly) avoids copying (although I don't know what happens under the hood so it may be no more efficient in memory usage ... but seems to me clearly more efficient syntactically.)

Comment: You do not need list(NULL), NULL is sufficient. e.g: dat[,4]=NULL

Comment: OP's question was how to delete multiple columns. dat[,4:5] <- NULL won't work. That is where list(NULL) comes in. It works for 1 or more columns.

Comment: This also doesn't work when trying to remove a duplicated column name.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Works fine for me. Either give a label if you want to remove the first  of the columns with the same name or give indices for each column you want to remove. If you have an example where it doesn't work I'd be interested to see it. Perhaps post it as a new question?

Comment: This syntax will also work for `data.table` as well. `dat[,c("mpg","cyl","wt")] <- NULL`

Answer (score 48):

There is a potentially more powerful strategy based on the fact that grep() will return a numeric vector. If you have a long list of variables as I do in one of my dataset, some variables that end in ".A" and others that end in ".B" and you only want the ones that end in ".A" (along with all the variables that don't match either pattern, do this:

```
dfrm2 <- dfrm[ , -grep("\\.B$", names(dfrm)) ]
```

For the case at hand, using Joris Meys example, it might not be as compact, but it would be:

```
DF <- DF[, -grep( paste("^",drops,"$", sep="", collapse="|"), names(DF) )]
```

Comment: If we define `drops` in the first place as `paste0("^", drop_cols, "$")`, this becomes much nicer (read: more compact) with `sapply`: `DF[ , -sapply(drops, grep, names(DF))]`

Answer (score 48):

If you want remove the columns by reference and avoid the internal copying associated with `data.frames` then you can use the `data.table` package and the function `:=`

You can pass a character vector names to the left hand side of the `:=` operator, and `NULL` as the RHS.

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10, c=1:10, d=1:10)
DT <- data.table(df)
# or more simply  DT <- data.table(a=1:10, b=1:10, c=1:10, d=1:10) #

DT[, c('a','b') := NULL]
```

If you want to predefine the names as as character vector outside the call to `[`, wrap the name of the object in `()` or `{}` to force the LHS to be evaluated in the calling scope not as a name within the scope of `DT`.

```
del <- c('a','b')
DT <- data.table(a=1:10, b=1:10, c=1:10, d=1:10)
DT[, (del) := NULL]
DT <-  <- data.table(a=1:10, b=1:10, c=1:10, d=1:10)
DT[, {del} := NULL]
# force or `c` would also work.
```

You can also use `set`, which avoids the overhead of `[.data.table`, **and also works for `data.frames`!**

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10, c=1:10, d=1:10)
DT <- data.table(df)

# drop `a` from df (no copying involved)

set(df, j = 'a', value = NULL)
# drop `b` from DT (no copying involved)
set(DT, j = 'b', value = NULL)
```

Comment: For some reason when using datatables, object size does not change in Rstudio's environmental windows. With dataframes, it does so immediately.

Answer (score 44):

Another `dplyr` answer.
Use `select(-column)`.

If your variables have some common naming structure, you might try `starts_with()`.  For example

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(5), var2 = rnorm(5), var3 = rnorm (5), 
                 var4 = rnorm(5), char1 = rnorm(5), char2 = rnorm(5))
df
#        var2      char1        var4       var3       char2       var1
#1 -0.4629512 -0.3595079 -0.04763169  0.6398194  0.70996579 0.75879754
#2  0.5489027  0.1572841 -1.65313658 -1.3228020 -1.42785427 0.31168919
#3 -0.1707694 -0.9036500  0.47583030 -0.6636173  0.02116066 0.03983268

df1 <- df %>% select(-starts_with("char"))

df1
#        var2        var4       var3       var1
#1 -0.4629512 -0.04763169  0.6398194 0.75879754
#2  0.5489027 -1.65313658 -1.3228020 0.31168919
#3 -0.1707694  0.47583030 -0.6636173 0.03983268
```

If you want to drop a sequence of variables in the data frame, you can use `:`.  For example if you wanted to drop `var2`, `var3`, and *all* variables in between, you'd just be left with `var1`:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% select(-c(var2:var3) )  
df2
#        var1
#1 0.75879754
#2 0.31168919
#3 0.03983268
```

Comment: Not to forget about all the other opportunities that come with ````select()````, such as ````contains()```` or ````matches()````, which also accepts regex.

Answer (score 38):

**Dplyr Solution**

I doubt this will get much attention down here, but if you have a list of columns that you want to remove, and you want to do it in a `dplyr` chain I use `one_of()` in the `select` clause:

Here is a simple, reproducable example:

```
undesired <- c('mpg', 'cyl', 'hp')

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  select(-one_of(undesired))
```

Documentation can be found by running `?one_of` or here:

http://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/dplyr_tutorial.html

Answer (score 28):

Another possibility:

```
df <- df[, setdiff(names(df), c("a", "c"))]
```

or

```
df <- df[, grep('^(a|c)$', names(df), invert=TRUE)]
```

Comment: Too bad that this is not upvoted more because use of `setdiff` is the optimal especially in the case of a very large number of columns.

Comment: Another angle on this: `df <- df[ , -which(grepl('a|c', names(df)))]`

Answer (score 25):

Out of interest, this flags up one of R's weird multiple syntax inconsistencies.  For example given a two-column data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1, y=2)
```

This gives a data frame

```
subset(df, select=-y)
```

but this gives a vector

```
df[,-2]
```

This is all explained in `?[` but it's not exactly expected behaviour.  Well at least not to me...

Answer (score 25):

```
DF <- data.frame(
  x=1:10,
  y=10:1,
  z=rep(5,10),
  a=11:20
)
DF
```

**Output:**

```
    x  y z  a
1   1 10 5 11
2   2  9 5 12
3   3  8 5 13
4   4  7 5 14
5   5  6 5 15
6   6  5 5 16
7   7  4 5 17
8   8  3 5 18
9   9  2 5 19
10 10  1 5 20
```

---

```
DF[c("a","x")] <- list(NULL)
```

**Output:**

```
        y z
    1  10 5
    2   9 5
    3   8 5
    4   7 5
    5   6 5
    6   5 5
    7   4 5
    8   3 5    
    9   2 5
    10  1 5
```

Answer (score 22):

Here is a `dplyr` way to go about it:

```
#df[ -c(1,3:6, 12) ]  # original
df.cut <- df %>% select(-col.to.drop.1, -col.to.drop.2, ..., -col.to.drop.6)  # with dplyr::select()
```

I like this because it's intuitive to read & understand without annotation and robust to columns changing position within the data frame. It also follows the vectorized idiom using `-` to remove elements.

Comment: Adding to this that (1) user want replace original df (2) magrittr has `%<>% ` operator to replace input object it could be simplified to `df %<>% select(-col.to.drop.1, -col.to.drop.2, ..., -col.to.drop.6)`

Comment: If you have a long list of columns to drop, with `dplyr`, it might be easier to group them and put only one minus: `df.cut <- df %>% select(-c(col.to.drop.1, col.to.drop.2, ..., col.to.drop.n))`

Answer (score 16):

I keep thinking there must be a better idiom, but for subtraction of columns by name, I tend to do the following:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10, c=1:10, d=1:10)

# return everything except a and c
df <- df[,-match(c("a","c"),names(df))]
df
```

Comment: Not a good idea to negate match - `df[,-match(c("e","f"),names(df))]`

Comment: .@JDLong - What if I want to drop column where the column name starts with `-`?

Answer (score 13):

There's a function called `dropNamed()` in Bernd Bischl's `BBmisc` package that does exactly this.

```
BBmisc::dropNamed(df, "x")
```

The advantage is that it avoids repeating the data frame argument and thus is suitable for piping in `magrittr` (just like the `dplyr` approaches):

```
df %>% BBmisc::dropNamed("x")
```

Answer (score 11):

Beyond `select(-one_of(drop_col_names))` demonstrated in earlier answers, there are a couple other `dplyr` options for dropping columns using `select()` that do not involve defining all the specific column names (using the dplyr starwars sample data for some variety in column names):

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>% 
  select(-(name:mass)) %>%        # the range of columns from 'name' to 'mass'
  select(-contains('color')) %>%  # any column name that contains 'color'
  select(-starts_with('bi')) %>%  # any column name that starts with 'bi'
  select(-ends_with('er')) %>%    # any column name that ends with 'er'
  select(-matches('^f.+s$')) %>%  # any column name matching the regex pattern
  select_if(~!is.list(.)) %>%     # not by column name but by data type
  head(2)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
homeworld species
  <chr>     <chr>  
1 Tatooine  Human  
2 Tatooine  Droid
```

If you need to drop a column that may or may not exist in the data frame, here's a slight twist using `select_if()` that unlike using `one_of()` will not throw an `Unknown columns:` warning if the column name does not exist. In this example 'bad_column' is not a column in the data frame:

```
starwars %>% 
  select_if(!names(.) %in% c('height', 'mass', 'bad_column'))
```

Answer (score 10):

Another solution if you don't want to use @hadley's above: If "COLUMN_NAME" is the name of the column you want to drop:

```
df[,-which(names(df) == "COLUMN_NAME")]
```

Comment: (1) Problem is to drop multiple columns at once. (2) It won't work if `COLUMN_NAME` is not in `df` (check yourself: `df<-data.frame(a=1,b=2)`). (3) `df[,names(df) != "COLUMN_NAME"]` is simpler and don't suffer from (2)

Comment: Can you give some more information about this answer?

Answer (score 6):

Provide the **data frame** and a string of **comma separated names** to remove:

```
remove_features <- function(df, features) {
  rem_vec <- unlist(strsplit(features, ', '))
  res <- df[,!(names(df) %in% rem_vec)]
  return(res)
}
```

**Usage**:

```
remove_features(iris, "Sepal.Length, Petal.Width")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ways you can do...

**Option-1:**

```
df[ , -which(names(df) %in% c("name1","name2"))]
```

**Option-2:**

```
df[!names(df) %in% c("name1", "name2")]
```

**Option-3:**

```
subset(df, select=-c(name1,name2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Drop and delete columns by columns name in data frame.

```
A <- df[ , c("Name","Name1","Name2","Name3")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of the columns you want to drop using `which`. Give these indexes a negative sign (`*-1`). Then subset on those values, which will remove them from the dataframe. This is an example.

```
DF <- data.frame(one=c('a','b'), two=c('c', 'd'), three=c('e', 'f'), four=c('g', 'h'))
DF
#  one two three four
#1   a   d     f    i
#2   b   e     g    j

DF[which(names(DF) %in% c('two','three')) *-1]
#  one four
#1   a    g
#2   b    h
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large `data.frame` and are low on memory use `[` [.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605268/10488504) [.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072346/10488504) [.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811993/10488504) [.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4607063/10488504) or [`rm` and `within`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072346/10488504) to *remove columns of a `data.frame`*, as `subset` is currently (R 3.6.2) using more memory - beside the hint of the manual to *use `subset` interactively*.

```
getData <- function() {
  n <- 1e7
  set.seed(7)
  data.frame(a = runif(n), b = runif(n), c = runif(n), d = runif(n))
}

DF <- getData()
tt <- sum(.Internal(gc(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))[13:14])
DF <- DF[setdiff(names(DF), c("a", "c"))] ##
#DF <- DF[!(names(DF) %in% c("a", "c"))] #Alternative
#DF <- DF[-match(c("a","c"),names(DF))]  #Alternative
sum(.Internal(gc(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))[13:14]) - tt
#0.1 MB are used

DF <- getData()
tt <- sum(.Internal(gc(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))[13:14])
DF <- subset(DF, select = -c(a, c)) ##
sum(.Internal(gc(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))[13:14]) - tt
#357 MB are used

DF <- getData()
tt <- sum(.Internal(gc(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))[13:14])
DF <- within(DF, rm(a, c)) ##
sum(.Internal(gc(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))[13:14]) - tt
#0.1 MB are used

DF <- getData()
tt <- sum(.Internal(gc(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))[13:14])
DF[c("a", "c")]  <- NULL ##
sum(.Internal(gc(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))[13:14]) - tt
#0.1 MB are used
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using the function `fselect` from the [collapse](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/) package. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
DF <- data.frame(
  x=1:10,
  y=10:1,
  z=rep(5,10),
  a=11:20
)

library(collapse)
fselect(DF, -z)
#>     x  y  a
#> 1   1 10 11
#> 2   2  9 12
#> 3   3  8 13
#> 4   4  7 14
#> 5   5  6 15
#> 6   6  5 16
#> 7   7  4 17
#> 8   8  3 18
#> 9   9  2 19
#> 10 10  1 20
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another **data.table** option which hasn't been posted yet is using the special verb `.SD`, which stands for subset of data. Together with the `.SDcols` argument you can select/drop columns by name or index.

```r
require(data.table)
# data
dt = data.table(
  A = LETTERS[1:5],
  B = 1:5,
  C = rep(TRUE, 5)
)
# delete B
dt[ , .SD, .SDcols =! 'B' ]
# delete all matches (i.e. all columns)
cols = grep('[A-Z]+', names(dt), value = TRUE)
dt[ , .SD, .SDcols =! cols ]
```

A summary of all the options for such a task in **data.table** can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202485/4742889)

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
+   a=1:5,
+   b=6:10,
+   c=rep(22,5),
+   d=round(runif(5)*100, 2),
+   e=round(runif(5)*100, 2),
+   f=round(runif(5)*100, 2),
+   g=round(runif(5)*100, 2),
+   h=round(runif(5)*100, 2)
+ )
> df
  a  b  c     d     e     f     g     h
1 1  6 22 76.31 39.96 66.62 72.75 73.14
2 2  7 22 53.41 94.85 96.02 97.31 85.32
3 3  8 22 98.29 38.95 12.61 29.67 88.45
4 4  9 22 20.04 53.53 83.07 77.50 94.99
5 5 10 22  5.67  0.42 15.07 59.75 31.21

> # remove cols: d g h
> newDf <- df[, c(1:3, 5), drop=TRUE]
> newDf
  a  b  c     e
1 1  6 22 39.96
2 2  7 22 94.85
3 3  8 22 38.95
4 4  9 22 53.53
5 5 10 22  0.42
```

> 