# How can I get a dataframe with columns temporarily removed by name?

Tags: r

For example, with the data set `mtcars`

```
mtcars[ , "cyl"]
```

and

```
mtcars[ , 2]
```

both give me the same column. So, since I can get everything BUT the column 2 like this:

```
mtcars[ , -2]
```

I don't expect this:

```
mtcars[ , -"cyl"]
Error in -"cyl" : invalid argument to unary operator
```

instead the best I can come up with is this:

```
mtcars[ , !colnames(mtcars)=="cyl"]
```

Is there an easier solution?

EDIT: It seems logical that if the first two techniques work, so should the second two techniques. I hoped I was missing something. The help pages for `?"["` or `?subset` don't explain this counterintuitive result. Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: @Joshua I think these are a bit different, here the focus is on deleting a single column by name, where the usual conventions don't work.

Comment: I made a slight change to the title and added "why" to the question.

Comment: The rules are explained in section 2.7 of the Introduction to R manual: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors

Comment: @Gavin: I agree, I misunderstood the question.  @jonw: I don't understand why you think the result from `mtcars[,-"cyl"]` is counterintuitive. `?"-"` indicates that the `-` operator works on numeric or complex vectors (or objects which can be coerced to them).  What do you expect the result of `-"cyl"` to be?

Comment: @jonw: I understand what you are saying.  I'm asking what you think R should return when you type `-"cyl"` at the command line.  What does `-"char"` mean?

Comment: @Joshua: Typing `"cyl"` or `"-cyl"` at the command line doesn't return anything useful anymore than `2` or `-2`, but while the latter can both be used in brackets with the dataframe name as a metaphor to get a certain result, the metaphor breaks down when I try to extend it to the former use... Why is it implemented this way? Maybe the answer is that `-"cyl"` (or `!"cyl"`) only makes sense to me :)

Comment: @jonw `-()` is a function and the R developers say it can't be used on a character vector (and not just because negating a string doesn't make sense). Because you can't negate a character vector, you can't supply negative strings to drop columns. The problem is with `-` and is the source of the error message you quote. Hence the rule that negative indices only work for numerics. Try `-"cyl"` not what you did to see the same error you got when subsetting.

Comment: @jonw: `"-cyl"` and `-"cyl"` are different things and you were asking about the latter, not the former (which is a string).  In order to use the negative subscripting metaphor with strings, you first must define what a negative string means.  I'm not aware of a language that defines what a negative string means; even if one did, it would be an idiosyncratic definition because `-"char"` is not well-defined like `-2`.

Comment: Makes sense. The last two comments are the explanation I was after. Any way to promote them to an answer for the checkmark?

Comment: @jonw for what it is worth, I added my comment to my answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**[Edit:]** Explanation of why negative string indices does not work:

`-()` is a function and the R developers say it can't be used on a character vector (and not just because negating a string doesn't make sense). Because you can't negate a character vector, you can't supply negative strings to drop columns. The problem is with `-` and is the source of the error message you quote. Hence the rule that negative indices only work for numerics. The source of the original error is:

```
> -"cyl"
Error in -"cyl" : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Note that in the comments to the Q, there was confusion that the negative version of `"cyl"` was `"-cyl"`, which it isn't, it is just another string. The R snippet above shows what was happening in the subsetting tried in the Question.

[Section 2.7](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors) of the "[An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html)" manual describes the allowed methods of subsetting.

**[Original:]**
The simplest way to remove a component is just to set that component to `NULL`:

```
> cars <- mtcars
> cars[, "cyl"] <- NULL ## or cars$cyl <- NULL
> names(cars)
 [1] "mpg"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

**[Edit:]**
In light of the Edit to the Q indicating a temporary drop of the named column was desired, then:

```
subset(mtcars, select = -cyl)
```

or

```
mtcars[, !names(mtcars) %in% "cyl"]
```

are options, and the former cleaner than the latter.

Comment: Edited the question: I'm looking for a temporary drop not permanent.

Answer (score 12):

I often use `subset`. An example using `mtcars`

```
> names(mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
> cars <- subset(mtcars, select=-c(mpg,cyl))
> names(cars)
[1] "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

There are some other ideas in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame).

Update: Subset also works for temporary removal of one or more columns by name, just replace `mtcars[,-2]` with `subset(mtcars, select=-cyl)`.

Comment: Thanks Seth, I never explored the options of subset and this will be a useful tool.

Comment: Actually the *select* arg is limited, it cannot be a negative character vector as @Gavin-Simpson notes above. So the only negative arguments you can get into it are a single character variable, or else a fixed list of string constants, like `select=-c(mpg,cyl)` .