# How to exclude a column when applying the sweep function to a data set

Tags: r

I am trying to subtract the mean (using the sweep function) from each column of the inbuilt longley data set in R, except from the ‘Year’ column. 
I have tried

```
sweep(apply(longley,2,mean),2,-c["Year"])
```

but is giving me the error

```
Error in c["Year"] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

It seems like a simple question but I just can't figure out how to exclude the 'Year' column in this function

Thank you

Comment: You could do this without `sweep`

Comment: I understand but I am in the process of learning R and I am playing around with the sweep function at the moment

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to drop columns by name in a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234117/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using:

```
  nm1 <- setdiff(colnames(longley), "Year")
  res1 <- longley[nm1]-colMeans(longley[nm1])[col(longley[nm1])]
```

Or using `sweep`

```
 res2 <- sweep(longley[nm1], 2, FUN=`-`, apply(longley[nm1], 2, mean))
 identical(res1, res2)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Or you can replace the `apply` with `colMeans`

```
 sweep(longley[nm1], 2, FUN=`-`, colMeans(longley[nm1]))
```