# How to drop all variables that do not cointain a string or another in R

Tags: r, dataset, subset

I manage to select all variables that contains an specific string in its name by:

```
df[grep("string1|string2",names(df))]
```

But what I really want to do is to keep those variables and drop the rest. I can do:

```
df2<-df[grep("string1|string2",names(df))]
```

But was wondering if I could simply drop those variables I am not interested in instead of creating another data frame.
I tried:

```
null<-X_total[grep("!(mean|std)",names(X_total))
```

But did not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try `grepl`, which returns a logical vector, which you can easily negate: `!grepl("(mean|std)", names(X_total)`.

Comment: Have a look at [How to drop columns by name in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234117/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-in-a-data-frame?rq=1)

Comment: OK, both of them worked fined. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, dropping all variables containing the strings Species or Sepal:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- select(iris, -matches("Species|Sepal"))
```

Output:

```
head(df, 3)
 Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          1.4         0.2
2          1.4         0.2
3          1.3         0.2
```