# R - Using rbind with list of data frames and a subset of columns

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, rbind

How can I rbind a list of data frames using only specific columns? Something like `do.call(rbind, data)` works fine, but I dont't know how to exclude a vector of specific columns. Dropping unnecessary columns afterwards seems is ok, but maybe there is a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: See: [How to drop columns by name in a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234117/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-in-a-data-frame)

Comment: Do you want to `merge` or `rbind`? You need to get your definitions straight.

Comment: Edit original post. I want to use `rbind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can simply use `subset` (thanks to @Jaap):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(data, subset, select=c("use_this", "and_this")))
```