# Subset dataframe according to conditional column name

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset a dataframe according to the value of a column which can change name over different versions of the dataframe. The value I want to test for is "----" in a column named either "SIC" or "NAICS".

Version 1:

```
df
  MSA  SIC EMPFLAG   EMP
1  40 ----         43372
2  40 07--           192
3  40 0700           192
```

Version 2:

```
df
  MSA NAICS EMPFLAG   EMP
1  40  ----         78945
2  40  07--           221
3  40  0700           221
```

The expect result is:

Version 1:

```
df
  MSA   EMP
1  40 43372
```

Version 2:

```
df
  MSA   EMP
1  40 78945
```

The following code doesn't work:

```
df <- ifelse("SIC" %in% colnames(df), 
             df[df$SIC=="----", c("MSA", "EMP")], 
             df[df$NAICS=="----", c("MSA", "EMP")])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the use of the vectorized `ifelse` when you don't really need it.

```
df <- if(any(grepl("SIC", colnames(df)))) {
         df[df$SIC=="----", c("MSA", "EMP")]
      } else {
         df[df$NAICS=="----", c("MSA", "EMP")]
      }
df
```

Note that you can also use `%in%`, which is probably simpler.

```
df <- if(any("SIC" %in% colnames(df))){
         df[df$SIC=="----", c("MSA", "EMP")]
      } else {
         df[df$NAICS=="----", c("MSA", "EMP")]
      }
```

Finally, after reading the answer by William Ashford, the following one-liner will do exactly what you've asked. Just use the fact that the columns in question are always the second one.

```
df <- df[df[, 2] == "----",-which(names(df) %in% c('SIC','NAICS','EMPFLAG'))]
```

The credits for this go to him.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [How to drop columns by name in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234117/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-in-a-data-frame)

Subset your dataframe such that,

```
df = df[,-which(names(df) %in% c('SIC','NAICS'))]
```

This was a very easy answer to find so mights I suggest you take a look through SO before posting questions.

Comment: @WilliamAshford Dropping the column is only secondary to what I'm trying to achieve. I need to test a value in the column before dropping it.

Comment: OK, this was added after original post, but I will endeavor to amend the answer so as to make it viable.

Comment: Disregard as I cannot significantly build on the simplicity of Rui Barradas's answer.