# Why does dropping which(FALSE) columns delete all columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5236518/10319707) warns of some scary behavior from `which`. Specifically, if you take any data frame, say `df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=2:6)`, and then try to subset it with something that evaluates to `which(FALSE)` (i.e. `integer(0)`), then you will delete every column in the data set. Why is this? Why would dropping all columns that correspond to `integer(0)` delete everything? Deleting nothing shouldn't destroy everything.

Example:

```
>df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=2:6)
>df
  x y
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 4 5
5 5 6
>df <- df[,-which(FALSE)]
>df
data frame with 0 columns and 5 rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
identical(integer(0), -integer(0))
# [1] TRUE
```

So, actually you're *selecting* nothing, rather than deleting nothing.

If you want to *delete* nothing, you could use a large negative integer, e.g. the largest possible.

```
df[, -.Machine$integer.max]
#   x y
# 1 1 2
# 2 2 3
# 3 3 4
# 4 4 5
# 5 5 6
```