# R lapply to remove column from list of dataframes

Tags: r, subset, lapply

I am trying to remove a single column from a list of dataframes using lapply with the below code (want to remove column name "ID" from both df1 and df2). I receive the following error message when running through command prompt:

Error in eval(substitute(select), nl, parent.frame()) :
object 'ID' not found
Calls: lapply -> FUN -> subset.data.frame -> eval -> eval

Any thoughts as to why the code produces an error?

```
df1 <- data.frame(
 "Qty" = c(15,29,12,53),
 "Type"   = c("A","B","B","E"),
 "ID"   = c("x123","y121","x556","y119"))

df2 <- data.frame(
 "Qty" = c(5,92,25,31),
 "Type"   = c("I","L","Z","K"),
 "ID"   = c("p433","q232","y344","l598"))

df_list <- mget(ls(pattern= "^df"))

df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) subset.data.frame(x, select=-c(ID)))

list2env(df_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Try `lapply(df_list, function(i){i$ID <- NULL; i})`

Comment: How would I write that to remove multiple columns?

Comment: [Here are ways to subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234117/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-in-a-data-frame). Just apply them in `lapply`

Answer (score 5):

Try this `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)         
#Data
df1 <- data.frame(
  "Qty" = c(15,29,12,53),
  "Type"   = c("A","B","B","E"),
  "ID"   = c("x123","y121","x556","y119"))

df2 <- data.frame(
  "Qty" = c(5,92,25,31),
  "Type"   = c("I","L","Z","K"),
  "ID"   = c("p433","q232","y344","l598"))

df_list <- mget(ls(pattern= "^df"))

df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {x <- x %>% select(-ID)})

list2env(df_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

The output (which will be released to environment):

```
df_list
$df1
  Qty Type
1  15    A
2  29    B
3  12    B
4  53    E

$df2
  Qty Type
1   5    I
2  92    L
3  25    Z
4  31    K
```

Comment: I receive the following error. Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `ID` doesn't exist.                                                                                             Maybe it's an issue with my configuration?

Comment: @MattGossett Check that all dataframes in your list have the column `ID`, use `lapply(yourlist,names)` and check that!

Comment: thanks! The code works when run through R Studio but not when run through command prompt. Not sure of the issue. This worked for me though lapply(df_list, function(i){i$ID <- NULL; i})

Comment: @MattGossett It is a valid option too! Fantastic!!!

Answer (score 1):

Base R solutions:

```
# Safer, directly specifying the name: 
Map(function(x){x[,names(x) != "ID"]}, df_list)

# If the data.frames have the same column order: 
lapply(df_list, "[", 1:2)
```