# Remove an entire column from a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

Does anyone know how to remove an entire column from a data.frame in R? For example if I am given this data.frame:

```
> head(data)
   chr       genome region
1 chr1 hg19_refGene    CDS
2 chr1 hg19_refGene   exon
3 chr1 hg19_refGene    CDS
4 chr1 hg19_refGene   exon
5 chr1 hg19_refGene    CDS
6 chr1 hg19_refGene   exon
```

and I want to remove the 2nd column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop columns in R data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-in-r-data-frame)

Answer (score 492, accepted):

You can set it to `NULL`.

```
> Data$genome <- NULL
> head(Data)
   chr region
1 chr1    CDS
2 chr1   exon
3 chr1    CDS
4 chr1   exon
5 chr1    CDS
6 chr1   exon
```

As pointed out in the comments, here are some other possibilities:

```
Data[2] <- NULL    # Wojciech Sobala
Data[[2]] <- NULL  # same as above
Data <- Data[,-2]  # Ian Fellows
Data <- Data[-2]   # same as above
```

You can remove multiple columns via:

```
Data[1:2] <- list(NULL)  # Marek
Data[1:2] <- NULL        # does not work!
```

Be careful with matrix-subsetting though, as you can end up with a vector:

```
Data <- Data[,-(2:3)]             # vector
Data <- Data[,-(2:3),drop=FALSE]  # still a data.frame
```

Comment: or you can use: Data <- Data[,-2]

Comment: @Ian do you even need the ","?

Comment: with the comma you can also control the "drop" argument, which when FALSE means the data.frame stays a data.frame when the result consists of only one column - without the comma you will always get a data.frame whether multiple columns are left or just one - drop is ignored for the [-2] extraction

Comment: @mdsumner `Data[-2]` don't need `drop` argument cause it always return `data.frame` from `data.frame`. And I think this is much better way to localized columns (and only columns) in `data.frame` (and it's faster). Check: `cars[-1]` (one col `data.frame`) or better `cars[-(1:2)]`: `data frame with 0 columns and 50 rows`.

Comment: You can also write Data[2] <- NULL

Comment: Minor tip: When removing multiple columns `Data[c(1,2)]<-list(NULL)` is needed.

Comment: how to remove them by calling names of columns?

Comment: does anyone know when this would fail? Calling it twice in a row works. But, calling names(x), x$y<-null, names(x) shows y during the second call to names(). Specifically, I have four DFs with one common column. It works on only three of the four

Comment: @MikePalmice: You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 86):

To remove one or more columns by name, when the column names are known (as opposed to being determined at run-time), I like the `subset()` syntax. E.g. for the data-frame

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3, d=2:4, c=3:5, b=4:6)
```

to remove just the `a` column you could do

```
Data <- subset( Data, select = -a )
```

and to remove the `b` and `d` columns you could do

```
Data <- subset( Data, select = -c(d, b ) )
```

You can remove all columns between `d` and `b` with:

```
Data <- subset( Data, select = -c( d : b )
```

As I said above, this syntax works only when the column names are known. It won't work when say the column names are determined programmatically (i.e. assigned to a variable). I'll reproduce this Warning from the `?subset` documentation:

> Warning:
>
> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively.
>   For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting
>   functions like '[', and in particular the non-standard evaluation
>   of argument 'subset' can have unanticipated consequences.

Answer (score 38):

(For completeness) If you want to remove columns by name, you can do this:

```
cols.dont.want <- "genome"
cols.dont.want <- c("genome", "region") # if you want to remove multiple columns

data <- data[, ! names(data) %in% cols.dont.want, drop = F]
```

Including `drop = F` ensures that the result will still be a `data.frame` even if only one column remains.

Answer (score 24):

The posted answers are very good when working with `data.frame`s. However, these tasks can be pretty inefficient from a memory perspective. With large data, removing a column can take an unusually long amount of time and/or fail due to `out of memory` errors. Package `data.table` helps address this problem with the `:=` operator:

```
library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1)
> dt[,a:=NULL]
     b c
[1,] 1 1
```

I should put together a bigger example to show the differences. I'll update this answer at some point with that.

Comment: The `data.table::set` function can be used on `data.frame`s to remove or modify a column instantly, without making copies.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891519/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-data-frame-in-place-destructively/17891970#17891970)

Answer (score 12):

With this you can remove the `column` and store `variable` into another `variable`.

```
df = subset(data, select = -c(genome) )
```

Answer (score 12):

There are several options for removing one or more columns with `dplyr::select()` and some helper functions. The helper functions can be useful because some do not require naming all the specific columns to be dropped. Note that to drop columns using `select()` you need to use a leading `-` to negate the column names.

Using the `dplyr::starwars` sample data for some variety in column names:

```
library(dplyr)

starwars %>% 
  select(-height) %>%                  # a specific column name
  select(-one_of('mass', 'films')) %>% # any columns named in one_of()
  select(-(name:hair_color)) %>%       # the range of columns from 'name' to 'hair_color'
  select(-contains('color')) %>%       # any column name that contains 'color'
  select(-starts_with('bi')) %>%       # any column name that starts with 'bi'
  select(-ends_with('er')) %>%         # any column name that ends with 'er'
  select(-matches('^v.+s$')) %>%       # any column name matching the regex pattern
  select_if(~!is.list(.)) %>%          # not by column name but by data type
  head(2)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
homeworld species
  <chr>     <chr>  
1 Tatooine  Human  
2 Tatooine  Droid
```

You can also drop by column number:

```
starwars %>% 
  select(-2, -(4:10)) # column 2 and columns 4 through 10
```

Comment: Great answer. Any idea on how to drop a column that contains a certain value in any of its rows (not in its column name as you proposed above)?

Comment: df[,-which(sapply(df, function(x) any(x == a)))], where df is your data frame and a is your specific value, e.g.: mtcars[,-which(sapply(mtcars, function(x) any(x==4)))]

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyR, the following works:

`data <- select(data, -genome)`

as per documentation found here [https://www.marsja.se/how-to-remove-a-column-in-r-using-dplyr-by-name-and-index/#:~:text=select(starwars%2C%20%2Dheight)](https://www.marsja.se/how-to-remove-a-column-in-r-using-dplyr-by-name-and-index/#:%7E:text=select(starwars%2C%20%2Dheight))

Answer (score 1):

I just thought I'd add one in that wasn't mentioned yet. It's simple but also interesting because in all my perusing of the internet I did not see it, even though the highly related %in% appears in many places.

```
df <- df[ , -which(names(df) == 'removeCol')]
```

Also, I didn't see anyone post grep alternatives. These can be very handy for removing multiple columns that match a pattern.

Comment: With logical, one can also go with `df <- df[ , !names(df) == 'removeCol']`

Answer (score 0):

`chr = chr[,-2]`
It's easier if you do this way, just remove the second column from the df and store it in the df again.