# Remove a column from a data frame by name

Tags: r, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove an entire column from a data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286313/remove-an-entire-column-from-a-data-frame-in-r)

Is there a better way to remove a column by name from a data frame than the following?

```
Orange[colnames(Orange) != "Age"]
```

I've tried the following and I get errors:

```
> Orange[-"Age"]
Error in -"age" : invalid argument to unary operator
> Orange[,-"Age"]
Error in -"age" : invalid argument to unary operator
> Orange[[,-"Age"]]
Error in -"age" : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set the column to NULL

```
> dat <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1)
> dat
  a b c
1 1 1 1
> dat$a <- NULL
> dat
  b c
1 1 1
> dat["b"] <- NULL
> dat
  c
1 1
```

Someone will come along and point out that `data.frame` will makes lots of copies of the data to do this simple task. When data gets big (millions of rows), this will take a lot of time and may not work due to memory constraints. If that's going to be an issue, use `data.table` and the `:=` operator:

```
library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1)
> dt[,a:=NULL]
     b c
[1,] 1 1
```

Comment: Could you add your answer to the question I linked to, so quality answers aren't dispersed across multiple questions?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Orange[-match("age",names(Orange))]
   Tree circumference
1     1            30
2     1            58
3     1            87
4     1           115
...
```

Comment: There is a much easier way, setting it to NULL, but it is discussed in the duplicate question (see above).