# remove character columns from a numeric data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like the one you see here.

```
     DRSi       TP        DOC        DN          date     Turbidity   Anions 
     158        5.9       3371       264        14/8/06      5.83    2246.02
     217        4.7       2060       428        16/8/06      6.04    1632.29
     181        10.6      1828       219        16/8/06      6.11    1005.00
     397        5.3       1027       439        16/8/06      5.74    314.19
     2204       81.2      11770      1827       15/8/06      9.64    2635.39
     307        2.9       1954       589        15/8/06      6.12    2762.02
     136        7.1       2712       157        14/8/06      5.83    2049.86
     1502       15.3      4123       959        15/8/06      6.48    2648.12
     1113       1.5       819        195        17/8/06      5.83    804.42
     329        4.1       2264       434        16/8/06      6.19    2214.89
     193        3.5       5691       251        17/8/06      5.64    1299.25
     1152       3.5       2865       1075       15/8/06      5.66    2573.78
     357        4.1       5664       509        16/8/06      6.06    1982.08
     513        7.1       2485       586        15/8/06      6.24    2608.35
     1645       6.5       4878       208        17/8/06      5.96    969.32
```

Before I got here i used the following code to remove those columns that had no values at all or some NA's.

```
    rem = NULL
    for(col.nr in 1:dim(E.3)[2]){
      if(sum(is.na(E.3[, col.nr]) > 0 | all(is.na(E.3[,col.nr])))){
        rem = c(rem, col.nr)
      }
    }
    E.4 <- E.3[, -rem]
```

Now I need to remove the "date" column but not based on its column name, rather based on the fact that it's a character string.

I've seen here ([Remove an entire column from a data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286313/remove-an-entire-column-from-a-data-frame-in-r)) already how to simply set it to NULL and other options but I want to use a different argument.

Comment: Please consider revising the body of your question. It is not very clear as it stands.

Comment: I'll go for `mydf <- mydf[sapply(mydf, is.numeric)]`

Comment: Thank you @dickoa, rewriting my df using is.numeric as argument to select out only those columns that are numeric was very useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First use `is.character` to find all columns with class `character`. However, make sure that your date is really a `character`, not a `Date` or a `factor`. Otherwise use `is.Date` or `is.factor` instead of `is.character`.

Then just subset the columns that are not characters in the data.frame, e.g.

```
df[, !sapply(df, is.character)]
```

Comment: Or, a destructive approach: `df[sapply(df, is.character)] <- list(NULL)`.

Comment: @shadow thanks for the tip about checking first if it's a character, factor or Date. It was in fact a factor so I switched is.character with is.factor and worked perfectly. Ananda Matho your example worked just as well, thank you!

Comment: @umbra, do consider marking shadow's answer as *accepted* if it solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Where can one find this interesting 'is.Date' function?

Comment: @WD_R: Apparently it does not exist... (Or at least I can't find it anymore.) You could define `is.Date <- function(d) "Date" %in% class(d)`, but that only finds dates of class `Date` and will not e.g. find `POSIXct` dates.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem but the answer above isn't resolve it for a Date columns (that's what I needed), so I've found another solution:

```
df[,-grep ("Date|factor|character", sapply (df, class))]
```

Will return you your df without Date, character and factor columns.