# Is it possible to modify a data.frame in-place (destructively)?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

It appears that one can add/delete a column to a [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/) *in-place*, i.e., **without copying** all the other columns over to a new table.

Is it possible to do that with a vanilla [`data.frame`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html)?

PS. I know how to add/delete columns "functionally", i.e., creating a new frame without modifying the original one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can delete or modify an existing column from a `data.frame` by reference with `data.table::set`. I doubt you can add a column without making a copy.  The reason that you can add a column to a `data.table` without making a copy is that `data.table` over allocates memory.  See [`?alloc.col`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/alloc.col) for more.

```
R> library(data.table)
R> data(mtcars)
R> tracemem(mtcars)
[1] "<0x59fef68>"
R> set(mtcars, j="mpg", value=NULL)        # remove a column
R> set(mtcars, j="cyl", value=rep(42, 32)) # modify a column
R> untracemem(mtcars)
R> str(mtcars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ cyl : num  42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

Compare that with normal data.frame operations

```
R> data(mtcars)
R> tracemem(mtcars)
[1] "<0x6b3ec30>"
R> mtcars[, "mpg"] <- NULL
tracemem[0x6b3ec30 -> 0x84de0c8]: 
tracemem[0x84de0c8 -> 0x84de410]: [<-.data.frame [<- 
tracemem[0x84de410 -> 0x84de6b0]: [<-.data.frame [<- 
R> tracemem(mtcars)
[1] "<0x84dca30>"
R> mtcars[, "cyl"] <- rep(42, 32)
tracemem[0x84dca30 -> 0x84dcc28]: 
tracemem[0x84dcc28 -> 0x84dd018]: [<-.data.frame [<- 
tracemem[0x84dd018 -> 0x84dff70]: [<-.data.frame [<- 
R> untracemem(mtcars)
R> data(mtcars)
```

Comment: If you'd done that with memory profiling on/results I'd be very impressed! :-)

Comment: When I ran it, it was almost instantaneous, and no movement on my system memory monitor when working with a 7+MM line dataframe. Running `names(object)` showed that column was no longer there.

Comment: FYI, you might want to try `pryr::address` which just gives you the memory location of any R object, without any extra messing around. There's also `track_copy` (https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/R/address.r) which is a first attempt at a nice way of tracking if any object is copied. It's a work in progress so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: @hadley I do not understand how `track_copy` is intended to be used.  Could you add an `@examples` section?