# filter data.table rows in-place

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to filter rows of a `data.table` in-place, i.e. without assigning it to a variable name?

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(a=1:5)
```

For example, can we do this without an assignment to `df`?

```
df <- df[a>3]
```

Comment: What do you mean? Not creating an object (in this case, what you called df)? You can, if this is what you mean, do `data.table(a=1:5)[a>3]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891519/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-data-frame-in-place-destructively

Comment: I think this would be equivalent to "deleting rows by references": https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-data-table/10791729#10791729

Comment: @rg255, no, what I meant is can we do this `df<-df[a>3]` in-place, meaning without writing `df` twice. But apperently this was asked before.