# How to drop columns in a nested data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

As i know there are different ways to `drop` a `column` of a `data frame` in `R` like

[Drop data frame columns by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame)

[How to drop columns by name in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234117/how-to-drop-columns-by-name-in-a-data-frame)

[Remove an entire column from a data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286313/remove-an-entire-column-from-a-data-frame-in-r)

Now My question: I have a data frame say `df` having `400 plus` files in the form of `nested` `data frame`.

```
        df
    [[1]]
                SignalIntensity SNR
        1   109 6.1823089314    0.8453576915
        2   110 10.1727771385   4.3837077591
        3   111 7.2922746927    1.0725751161
        4   112 8.8984671629    2.3192184908
        5   113 9.5910338232    3.7133402249
        6   114 7.9850187685    1.5008899345
        7   116 7.7893230124    1.3636655582
                       .
                       .
                       .
    [[2]]

            SignalIntensity SNR
    1   109 6.1823089314    0.8453576915
    2   110 10.1727771385   4.3837077591
    3   111 7.2922746927    1.0725751161
    4   112 8.8984671629    2.3192184908
    5   113 9.5910338232    3.7133402249
    6   114 7.9850187685    1.5008899345
    7   116 7.7893230124    1.3636655582
                  .
                  .
                  .
[[3]]

        ID  SignalIntensity SNR
    1   109 6.1823089314    0.8453576915
    2   110 10.1727771385   4.3837077591
    3   111 7.2922746927    1.0725751161
    4   112 8.8984671629    2.3192184908
    5   113 9.5910338232    3.7133402249
    6   114 7.9850187685    1.5008899345
    7   116 7.7893230124    1.3636655582
                   .
                   .
                   .
 and so on.....
```

I want to remove `column 1` from all the `400 plus` files. The `column 1` header may be present or absent.

I know to use df[[1]][,-1] to remove `column 1` of first file. In order to do for all the files i have to repeat it `400` or so times to make the work done. There may be `1` or `2` line of code in `R` to do this. How?? help appreciated.

Final data frame is expected to be like

```
df
     [[1]]
                    SignalIntensity SNR
            1       6.1823089314    0.8453576915
            2       10.1727771385   4.3837077591
            3       7.2922746927    1.0725751161
            4       8.8984671629    2.3192184908
            5       9.5910338232    3.7133402249
            6       7.9850187685    1.5008899345
            7       7.7893230124    1.3636655582
                           .
                           .
                           .
        [[2]]

                SignalIntensity SNR
        1       6.1823089314    0.8453576915
        2       10.1727771385   4.3837077591
        3       7.2922746927    1.0725751161
        4       8.8984671629    2.3192184908
        5       9.5910338232    3.7133402249
        6       7.9850187685    1.5008899345
        7       7.7893230124    1.3636655582
                      .
                      .
                      .
    [[3]]

                SignalIntensity SNR
        1       6.1823089314    0.8453576915
        2       10.1727771385   4.3837077591
        3       7.2922746927    1.0725751161
        4       8.8984671629    2.3192184908
        5       9.5910338232    3.7133402249
        6       7.9850187685    1.5008899345
        7       7.7893230124    1.3636655582
                       .
                       .
                       .
     and so on.....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is with a loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
  df[[i]] <- df[[i]][-1]
}
```

Or without the loop, using lapply:

```
df2 <- lapply(df, subset, select=-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Isn't there any thing without loop

Comment: Great. This is what i was looking forward.