# How does one ignore the "moral" column in R

Tags: r, preprocessor

```
moral   verw    ho       dog
4       1049    1         2
4       2799    1         3
2       8412    4         4
4       2122    1         3
4       2171    1         3
4       2241    1         2
4       3398    1         4
```

I was normalizing a dataset using 
`noid = data.Normalization(newx,type="n4")` but I want to ignore JUST the "moral" column but normalize everything else.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `data.Normalization(newx[-1],type="n4")` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove an entire column from a data.frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286313/remove-an-entire-column-from-a-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

As David Arenburg suggested in his comment, if you don't pass the *moral* column to the normalisation routine it will obviously be ignored. If you want it to be included in the normalized dataset you can do something like this:

```
noid <- data.Normalization(newx[-1], type="n4")
noid <- cbind(moral=newx[1], noid)
```

Comment: Colonel Beauvel, he didn't write it though. I simply expanded on his (brief) comment a bit. I would have simply added a comment to the question to point this out, if I could. Not trying to take undue credit here. In any case, if David Arenburg objects to any of this I'm sure he can speak for himself.