# Is this the right way to drop a column in R?

Tags: r

Is this the correct way to delete a column from a dataframe in R?
Or there is a better way?

```
dataframe$column <- NULL
```

Comment: It's a robust way. `dataframe[["column"]] <- NULL` is _slightly_ more robust because it doesn't do partial matching, but that's rarely an issue.

Comment: It might be worth/interesting to also take a look at this post: [Remove an entire column from a data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286313/remove-an-entire-column-from-a-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Thanks alistaire and Maurits Evers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is by using negative subscripts:

Say, you want to remove column #2 from the data frame:

```
 df <- df[,-2]
```

If you want to remove several columns, use `c`; for example:

```
 df <- df[,-c(2, 5, 7:10)]
```

Comment: Okay. thanks Chris. Was just wondering what is the most efficient way though. :)

Answer (score 0):

using `dplyr` from `tidyverse` you can pipe in the ability to drop a single or multiple columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

dataframe <- dataframe %>%
  select(-column)
```