# How to delete the very first column-first row in R as per this shows in attached pic

Tags: r

I have uploaded the excel file into the R environment when I view(data) then this shows like [image: this]

this red circle has "...1" which is not actually in the excel sheet, so how to delete it in the R?

Comment: how did you load that file in Rstudio ? What is its extension ?

Comment: colnames(x)[1] <-" "

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to rename the first column:

```
colnames(data)[1] <- ""
```

Otherwise you can either sett it to Null

```
data[1] <- NULL
```

... or subset the dataframe ...

```
data <- data[,-1]
```

... but there are [lots of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286313/remove-an-entire-column-from-a-data-frame-in-r) to do this.

Comment: this is deleting the entire column, I want to delete only the first corner cell (inside the red circle); Moreover when I run the "heatmap" then "Error in sample.int(m, k) : vector size cannot be NA/NaN" showing

Comment: Rename the first col: `colnames(data)[1] <- ""
`

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse`, we could use `column_to_rownames` from `tibble`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df <- df %>%
        column_to_rownames(var = "...1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the first column as rowname and then delete the first column.

```
rownames(df) <- df[[1]]
df[, 1] <- NULL
```