# R: Unselect matrix or data.frame columns by name

Tags: r, matrix, unselect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drop Columns R Data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame)

Assuming a matrix with 3 named columns "A", "B", C", I can unselect columns "B" and "C" like this:

```
df[, -c(2, 3)]
```

But what if I want to use column names? How can I df[, -c("B", "C")]?

Comment: Agree it is duplicate. Comment: The -grep() strategy is more general.

Answer (score 3):

Matching is your friend:

```
R> DF <- data.frame(A=1:2, B=2:3, C=3:4)
R> DF[, !(colnames(DF) %in% c("B","C")), drop=FALSE]
  A
1 1
2 2
R>
```

The key is that you need boolean vectors for indexing (or else, numeric indices).  So any expression creating booleans will do.

Comment: Thanks, a lot more complicate than the - operator though :(

Comment: So just define a new '-' (alike) operator or function.

Comment: Good suggestion but then I'm not clear why it's not already defined. Why only for indexes? After all I can still use the column names to select columns: DF[, c("A", "B")]