# How can I delete column from data frame without causing a memory allocation error?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to remove a column from a large data frame by setting it to NULL (`x$abc=NULL`). Surprisingly, this caused a memory usage spike and I got a typical out-of-memory error message:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 657.76 Mb   In addition: Warning
>   messages:   ...

Why is this happening? And how do I avoid it?

Comment: Consider using data tables.

Comment: Specifically, take a look at this answer once you have a `data.table` format for your dataset - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19504279/496803

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13371575/1385941 regarding using `data.table` or at least `data.table::set` on `data.frame` objects