# Column deletion by characterising the value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe (data.table) I want to remove all columns where all values are  equal to zero. I have read "Remove columns from dataframe where ALL values are NA" but doesn't help me much. My dataset has multiple columns over 3000. This reproducible is data.frame but how to tackle the same for data.table

Comment: Please show what you have tried after posting several somewhat similar questions recently

Comment: And note that none of the columns in your example has only zeros in it.

Comment: Column no.3 has three zeros and rest NAs

Comment: right, and `NA != 0`

Comment: Sorry didn't get you

Comment: NA is not the same as zero

Comment: Nope NA is not available data where 0 is resultant of two columns being divided

Comment: Dou you want to remove the columns containing only zeros (you have no such columns) or only zeros and NA's? And do you need a solution for data.frame or data.table?

Comment: I'm removing the data.table tag, since your example data is, in fact, not a data.table. This is the standard dupe for the data.table question, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202413/how-do-you-delete-a-column-in-data-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this if you want to get rid of all columns that have all NA's or Zeroes. You can modify the condition accordingly if you want NAs only or zeroes only:

```
df <- df[, sapply(df, function(x) !all(is.na(x) | x == 0))]
```