# Remove specific columns from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to remove a group of columns from a data frame ([followed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202413/how-do-you-delete-a-column-by-name-in-data-table)) but I get an error in return.

Specifically, size of the data frame (NNF.data) is 34233 rows with 147 columns:

```
[118] "NNF.2015.03.EUR"      "NNF.2015.04.EUR"      "NNF.2015.05.EUR"     
[121] "NNF.2015.06.EUR"      "NNF.2015.07.EUR"      "NNF.2015.08.EUR"     
[124] "NNF.2015.09.EUR"      "NNF.2015.10.EUR"      "NNF.2015.11.EUR"     
[127] "NNF.2015.12.EUR"      "NNF.2016.01.EUR"      "NNF.2016.02.EUR"     
[130] "NNF.2016.03.EUR"      "NNF.2016.04.EUR"      "NNF.2016.05.EUR"     
[133] "NNF.2016.06.EUR"      "NNF.2016.07.EUR"      "NNF.2016.08.EUR"     
[136] "YTD.NNF.Year2005.EUR" "YTD.NNF.Year2006.EUR" "YTD.NNF.Year2007.EUR"
[139] "YTD.NNF.Year2008.EUR" "YTD.NNF.Year2009.EUR" "YTD.NNF.Year2010.EUR"
[142] "YTD.NNF.Year2011.EUR" "YTD.NNF.Year2012.EUR" "YTD.NNF.Year2013.EUR"
[145] "YTD.NNF.Year2014.EUR" "YTD.NNF.Year2015.EUR" "YTD.NNF.Year2016.EUR"
```

What I want to do is to remove the columns from 136-147, or the ones that contain YTD in their name.

I tried to use

```
NNF.data[, grep("YTD", names(NNF.data)):= NULL]
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(NNF.data, , `:=`(grep("YTD", names(NNF.data)),  : 
  could not find function ":="
```

Similarly, I tried

```
NNF.data[, which(grepl("YTD", colnames(NNF.data))):=NULL]
```

but again, I get

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(NNF.data, , `:=`(which(grepl("YTD", colnames(NNF.data))),  : 
  could not find function ":="
```

Any suggestions please?
I made sure that NNF.data is a data frame

```
> is.data.frame(NNF.data)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `:=` works for `data.table` objects. Are you working with `data.frame` or `data.table`?

Comment: I didn't know that Carles, I am working with data.frame. Is there anything equivalent for data frame?

Comment: If there is, can you please post as an answer to upvote it? Thanks

Comment: `NNF.data[startsWith(names(NNF.data), "YTD")] <- list(NULL)`, but data.table is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:=` only works for `data.table` objects. If you are working with a `data.frame` you can try this:

```
df = data.frame(First = c(1,2,3), AVSecond = c(3,4,5), ThirdAV = c(6,7,8), Fourth = c(10,22,2))

df = df[-c(grep("AV", colnames(df)), 4)]
```

This will remove the columns with `'AV'` in it and the Fourth column. Output:

```
  First
1     1
2     2
3     3
```

Comment: `-grep(...)` is dangerous.  Consider the case where no values are matched.  You get `integer(0)`.

Comment: If no values are matched, it will remove only Fourth column. I'm not sure if you meant this or not

Comment: Sure, but when that 4 isn't in there, you get no columns at all where you would want them all.

Comment: For example, try `df[-grep("xxx", colnames(df))]`.  In this case of no matches, there are no columns to remove.  You would want the whole data set returned, but you get nothing.  `!grepl(...)` is safer.  Or `!startsWith(...)`, as I mentioned in my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = data.frame(YTD.NNF.Year2009.EUR=c(1,2,3),NNF.2016.06.EUR=c(3,4,5),HJK=c(6,7,8))
nm = colnames(df)  
numb = grepl("\\bYTD\\b", nm)
df = df[,-numb]
```

Comment: `-numb` probably won't work, since `numb` is a logical vector

Comment: numb is a logi [1:3] TRUE FALSE FALSE

Comment: Exactly.  Now do `-` on that.  I think you meant `!` for negation.

Comment: So remove 1 column (2 and 3 leave) which is "YTD.NNF.Year2009.EUR" and it contains YTD so should be removed.