# Programming-safe version of subset - to evaluate its condition while called from another function

Tags: r

As `subset()` manual states:

> **Warning**: This is a convenience function intended for use interactively

I learned from [this great article](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) not only the secret behind this warning, but a good understanding of `substitute()`, `match.call()`, `eval()`, `quote()`, ‍`call`, `promise` and other related R subjects, that are a little bit complicated.

Now I understand what's the warning above for. A super-simple implementation of `subset()` could be as follows:

```
subset = function(x, condition) x[eval(substitute(condition), envir=x),]
```

While `subset(mtcars, cyl==4)` returns the table of rows in `mtcars` that satisfy `cyl==4`, enveloping `subset()` in another function fails:

```
sub = function(x, condition) subset(x, condition)

sub(mtcars, cyl == 4)
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'cyl' not found
```

Using the original version of `subset()` also produces exactly the same error condition. This is due to the limitation of `substitute()-eval()` pair: It works fine while `condition` is `cyl==4`, but when the `condition` is passed through the enveloping function `sub()`, the `condition` argument of `subset()` will be no longer `cyl==4`, but the nested `condition` in the `sub()` body, and the `eval()` fails - it's a bit complicated.

But does it exist any other implementation of `subset()` with **exactly the same arguments** that would be programming-safe - i.e. able to evaluate its condition while it's called by another function?

Comment: @BenBolker Have you seen the accepted answer below? Do you believe it does not work?

Comment: The "great article" link goes to a blank Wiki page.  Did you mean [this article](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because it's such mind-bending fun (??), here is a slightly different solution that addresses a problem Hadley pointed to in comments to my accepted solution.

Hadley [posted a gist](https://gist.github.com/3880527) demonstrating a situation in which my accepted function goes awry. The twist in that example (copied below) is that a symbol passed to `SUBSET()` is defined in the body (rather than the arguments) of one of the calling functions; it thus gets captured by `substitute()` instead of the intended global variable. Confusing stuff, I know.

```
f <- function() {
  cyl <- 4
  g()
}

g <- function() {
  SUBSET(mtcars, cyl == 4)$cyl
}
f()
```

Here is a better function that will only substitute the values of symbols found in calling functions' argument lists. It works in all of the situations that Hadley or I have so far proposed.

```
SUBSET <- function(`_dat`, expr) {
   ff <- sys.frames()
   n <- length(ff)
   ex <- substitute(expr)
   ii <- seq_len(n)
   for(i in ii) {
       ## 'which' is the frame number, and 'n' is # of frames to go back.
       margs <- as.list(match.call(definition = sys.function(n - i),
                                   call = sys.call(sys.parent(i))))[-1]
       ex <- eval(substitute(substitute(x, env = ll),
                             env = list(x = ex, ll = margs)))
   }
   `_dat`[eval(ex, envir = `_dat`),]
}

## Works in Hadley's counterexample ...
f()
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

## ... and in my original test cases.
sub <- function(x, condition) SUBSET(x, condition)
sub2 <- function(AA, BB) sub(AA, BB)

a <- SUBSET(mtcars, cyl == 4)  ## Direct call to SUBSET()
b <- sub(mtcars, cyl == 4)     ## SUBSET() called one level down
c <- sub2(mtcars, cyl == 4)
all(identical(a, b), identical(b, c))
# [1] TRUE
```

**IMPORTANT:** Please note that this still is not (nor can it be made into) a *generally* useful function. There's simply no way for the function to know which symbols you want it to use in all of the substitutions it performs as it works up the call stack.  There are many situations in which users would *want* it to use the values of symbols assigned to within function bodies, but this function will always ignore those.

Comment: Does this pass the `subscramble` example in @hadley's article?

Comment: @pete -- No, it doesn't (although my original answer below *does* pass that test). Maddening as it it, I'll have to wait to revisit this when I've got more time to think about it, but for now, I think my other answer is the better one.

Answer (score 8):

The [ function is what you're looking for. ?"[". `mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4,]` is equivalent to the subset command and is "programming" safe.

```
sub = function(x, condition) {
 x[condition,]
}

sub(mtcars, mtcars$cyl==4)
```

Does what you're asking without the implicit `with()` in the function call.  The specifics are complicated, however a function like:

```
sub = function(x, quoted_condition) {
  x[with(x, eval(parse(text=quoted_condition))),]
}

sub(mtcars, 'cyl==4')
```

Sorta does what you're looking for, but there are edge cases where this will have unexpected results.

---

using `data.table` and the `[` subset function you can get the implicit `with(...)` you're looking for.

```
library(data.table)
MT = data.table(mtcars)

MT[cyl==4]
```

there are better, faster ways to do this subsetting in `data.table`, but this illustrates the point well.

---

using `data.table` you can also construct expressions to be evaluated later

```
cond = expression(cyl==4)

MT[eval(cond)]
```

these two can now be passed through functions:

```
wrapper = function(DT, condition) {
  DT[eval(condition)]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, but I am not looking an implementation of function sub(), but the function subset() with the same implicit with() that is also able to be called from sub(). I am eager to find out is there anyway to resolve the limitation of substitute()-eval() pair in this case.

Comment: @AliSharifi  The function would be `[`.  This is particularly clear using the `data.table` package.  see my edit

Comment: You missed the point: I am not looking an implementation of sub(). I am looking an implementation of subset() that the condition can be passed through sub() to it. Have you seen my implementation of subset in the updated question?

Comment: @AliSharifi I saw it, and I don't think I understand why you would do this sort of nested calls to subset and how its any different than my data.table example. I'll make another edit though.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I modified the question.

Comment: @AliSharifi the specifics of `eval` `parse` `expression` and the like are at the edges of my understanding of R also.  I'd love to learn more specifics about how its all working!

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read the reference I have provided  in the question. Then both of us can wait until someone provides an answer, or tells why it's impossible :)

Comment: @AliSharifi Justin is (basically) correct. The function that does the same thing as `subset` but is "programming safe" is `[.data.frame`. If you look closely you'll see they have the same four arguments.

Comment: @AliSharifi you can't have both convenience and safety. When you're writing a function, it's your job to spend time to save the users of the function time. Programming with functions that use non-standard evaluation is a bad idea because they tend to produce extremely hard to debug errors. And since you write the function once, but call it many times, you're better off investing a little extra time early on.

Comment: @Justin using `quote` in this circumstance is slightly more correct/idiomatic. I've attempted to explain some of this stuff at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Computing-on-the-language

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative version of `subset()` which continues to work even when it's nested -- at least as long as the logical subsetting expression (e.g. `cyl == 4`) is supplied to the top-level function call.

It works by climbing up the call stack, `substitute()`ing at each step to ultimately capture the logical subsetting expression passed in by the user. In the call to `sub2()` below, for example, the `for` loop works up the call stack from `expr` to `x` to `AA` and finally to `cyl ==4`.

```
SUBSET <- function(`_dat`, expr) {
    ff <- sys.frames()
    ex <- substitute(expr)
    ii <- rev(seq_along(ff))
    for(i in ii) {
        ex <- eval(substitute(substitute(x, env=sys.frames()[[n]]),
                              env = list(x = ex, n=i)))
    }
    `_dat`[eval(ex, envir = `_dat`),]
}

## Define test functions that nest SUBSET() more and more deeply
sub <- function(x, condition) SUBSET(x, condition)
sub2 <- function(AA, BB) sub(AA, BB)

## Show that it works, at least when the top-level function call
## contains the logical subsetting expression
a <- SUBSET(mtcars, cyl == 4)  ## Direct call to SUBSET()
b <- sub(mtcars, cyl == 4)     ## SUBSET() called one level down
c <- sub2(mtcars, cyl == 4)    ## SUBSET() called two levels down

identical(a,b)
# [1] TRUE
> identical(a,c)
# [1] TRUE
a[1:5,]
#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
```

** For some explanation of the construct inside the `for` loop, see [Section 6.2](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Substitutions), paragraph 6 of the R Language Definition manual.

Comment: While this answers the question, I think this is a dangerous function, because it is considerably more complicated that original, and I suspect prone to failure in some setups.  There's general no way to make functions that use non-standard evaluation safe for programming with - it's a tradeoff between convenience and safety. You can't have both.

Comment: Simple example of where it doesn't work: `x <- 4; subset(mtcars, cyl == x); SUBSET(mtcars, cyl == x)`

Comment: So Josh, Would you please provide a correction? Maybe the enclos parameter of eval() function is needed to be used

Comment: @AliSharifi: I can appreciate wanting both convenience and safety, but I have to agree with Hadley here.  You could make the function more baroque, and have it work in a wider range of circumstances, but there would still be corner cases where it failed (perhaps in a silent, nasty way rather than with an outright error). I think it's *very* hard/nearly impossible to do this in R -- and I don't know enough CS to know if one *could* design a language where one could do this completely safely and generally ...

Comment: @BenBolker So would you please modify your answer with this comment that I mark it again as accepted? Thanks

Comment: I didn't provide an answer. To me, either Josh's or Justin's answer would be acceptable, but it's your call.

Comment: @hadley and Ben -- I couldn't agree more. I *almost* prefaced my answer with a warning that I wouldn't advise ever using a function like this, but thought I wouldn't clutter it with that. I only answered the question because it seemed an interesting puzzle in evaluation, and the answer highlights the reasons that `subset()` doesn't work when nested.

Comment: @hadley -- FWIW, your counterexample would work if you had used a variable with any name **other** than `x` (e.g. `y <- 4; SUBSET(mtcars, cyl == y)`. (That problem is caused by a clash with the name of `SUBSET`'s first argument, also called `x`.) I'll rename it to `dat`, probably a better of variable name, and less likely to be passed in as part of the logical expression.

Comment: @AliSharifi -- I made the simplest of modifications to show that hadley's *particular* counterexample wasn't really fatal. You still shouldn't use this programatically, though... ;)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: or call it `..DAT` or something.  If someone uses `..DAT` as a variable name they're asking for trouble anyway.

Comment: @BenBolker -- True, that. I think I just discovered why folks so often use argument names of that form (`.*`): they've walked this path before me.

Comment: Do you think I picked `x` on accident? ;)  Functions that fail randomly depending on the _name_ of the input variables are not very nice.  Also see the first argument of `transform`...  (And a better solution is `eval(ex, dat, parent.frame())`

Comment: BTW, I've now come to the conclusion that your function is genius, evil genius, but genius none the less ;)

Comment: And finally, a deconstruction of how `SUBSET` works, and a case where it will fail at https://gist.github.com/3880527

Comment: @hadley -- I *did* think you'd picked it on accident, but should have known better ;) Thanks also for pointing me to `transform()`: I just stole its named argument's name and used it in an edit above. Finally, why is an explicit `enclos=parent.frame()` better in this setting? Could you explain when that might make a difference?  Cheers.

Comment: @hadley -- Your gist inspired me to post a revised function as another answer. It avoids the pitfall you pointed out (though I'm sure you'll find another one to torment me with). Anyway, couldn't resist the challenge. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Here is a new version which fixes two problems:

a) The previous version simply traversed `sys.frames()` backwards.  This version follows `parent.frames()` until it reaches `.GlobalEnv`.  This is important in, e.g., `subscramble`, where `scramble`'s frame should be ignored.

b) This version has a single `substitute` per level.  This prevents the second `substitute` call from substituting symbols from one level higher that were introduced by the first `substitute` call.

```
subset <- function(x, condition) {

    call <- substitute(condition)
    frames <- sys.frames()
    parents <- sys.parents()

    # starting one frame up, keep climbing until we get to .GlobalEnv 
    i <- tail(parents, 1)
    while(i != 0) {

        f <- sys.frames()[[i]]

        # copy x into f, except for variable with conflicting names.
        xnames <- setdiff(ls(x), ls(f))
        for (n in xnames) assign(n, x[[n]], envir=f)

        call <- eval(substitute(substitute(expr, f), list(expr=call)))

        # leave f the way we found it
        rm(list=xnames, envir=f)

        i <- parents[i]
    }

    r <- eval(call, x, .GlobalEnv)

    x[r, ]
}
```

This version passes @hadley's test from the comments:

```
mtcars $ condition <- 4; subscramble(mtcars, cyl == 4)
```

Unfortunately the following two examples now behave differently:

```
cyl <- 6; subset(mtcars, cyl==4)
local({cyl <- 6; subset(mtcars, cyl==4)})
```

---

This is a slight modification of Josh's first function.  At each frame in the stack, we substitute from `x` before substituting from the frame.  This means that symbols in the data frame take precedence at every step.  We can avoid pseudo-gensyms like `_dat` by skipping `subset`'s frame in the `for` loop.

```
subset <- function(x, condition) {

    call <- substitute(condition)
    frames <- rev(sys.frames())[-1]

    for(f in frames) {

        call <- eval(substitute(substitute(expr, x), list(expr=call)))
        call <- eval(substitute(substitute(expr, f), list(expr=call)))
    }

    r <- eval(call, x, .GlobalEnv)

    x[r, ]
}
```

This version works in the simple case (it's worth checking that we haven't had a regression):

```
subset(mtcars, cyl == 4)
#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
# Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

It also works with `subscramble` and `f`:

```
scramble <- function(x) x[sample(nrow(x)), ]
subscramble <- function(x, condition) scramble(subset(x, condition))

subscramble(mtcars, cyl == 4) $ cyl
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

f <- function() {cyl <- 4; g()}
g <- function() subset(mtcars, cyl == 4) $ cyl

g()
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

And even works in some trickier situations:

```
gear5 <- function(z, condition) {

    x <- 5
    subset(z, condition & (gear == x))
}

x <- 4
gear5(mtcars, cyl == x)
#                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.7  0  1    5    2
# Lotus Europa  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

---

The lines inside the `for` loop might require some explanation.  Suppose `call` is assigned as follows:

```
call <- quote(y == x)
str(call)
# language y == x
```

We want to substitute the value `4` for `x` in `call`.  But the straightforward way doesn't work, since we want the contents of `call`, not the symbol `call`.

```
substitute(call, list(x=4))
# call
```

So we build the expression we need, using another `substitute` call.

```
substitute(substitute(expr, list(x=4)), list(expr=call))
# substitute(y == x, list(x = 4))
```

Now we have a language object that describes what we want to do.  All that's left it to actually do it:

```
eval(substitute(substitute(expr, list(x=4)), list(expr=call)))
# y == 4
```

Comment: @hadley: Even worse, something like:
`mtcars$condition <- sample(c(T, F), nrow(mtcars), repl=T)`. 
In that case, it's not even clear what the correct behaviour IS, let alone how to achieve it!

Comment: I think that's the basic problem with trying to fix the behaviour of subset: you're looking for a symbol in many different places, and depending on what names you use it will behave differently. Non-lexical scoping makes it much harder to reason about a function.