# Referencing columns in R without quotes

Tags: r

For example in the package ggplot2, you can specify: `ggplot2(data = mydataframe, aes(x=mycolumnname))`. I'm looking to do something like that however the only solution I have found is to use the double bracket operator with the name in quotes. For example passing:

```
a = myfunction(data = mydataframe, name = "mycolumnname") {
    ...
    col = mydataframe[[name]]
    ...
}
```

I know this is being picky, but is there a way I could do this where the user does not have to input the parameter name in quotes? I see it all the time in R functions.

Comment: take a look at the dot (`?"."`) function in `plyr`... but there be demons... The discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850141/programming-safe-version-of-subset-to-evaluate-its-condition-while-called-from/12850252#12850252) while directly unrelated will shed some light on the demons I speak of.

Comment: If you see it all the time in R functions, nobody is stopping you from looking at the code of those functions yourself. However, I prefer to avoid unforseen problems by using characters as parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
myfunction <- function(DF,col) {
  DF[,as.character(substitute(col))]
}

dat <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10)

myfunction(dat,b)
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

See the comment by @Justin concerning the dangers.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is using `match.call` :

```
  myfunction <- function(DF,col) {
    pars <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
    DF[,as.character(pars$col)]

  }
```

Then all theses statements are equivalents:

```
  myfunction(dat,b)
  myfunction(dat,col=b)
  myfunction(dat,col="b")
```

Of course you can generalize this for all function arguments :

```
  myfunction <- function(DF,col) {
    pars <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
    get(as.character(pars$DF))[,as.character(pars$col)]
  }
```