# Avoiding redundancy when selecting rows in a data frame

Tags: r

My code is littered with statements of the following taste:

```
selected <- long_data_frame_name[long_data_frame_name$col1 == "condition1" & 
long_data_frame_name$col2 == "condition2" & !is.na(long_data_frame_name$col3),
selected_columns]
```

The repetition of the data frame name is tedious and error-prone. Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `with`

For instance

```
sel.ID <- with(long_data_frame_name, col1==2 & col2<0.5 & col3>0.2)
selected <- long_data_frame_name[sel.ID, selected_columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Several ways come to mind.

If you think about it, you are subsetting your data. Hence use the subset function (base package):

```
your_subset <- subset(long_data_frame_name,
                      col1 == "cond1" & "cond2" == "cond2" & !is.na(col3),
                      select = selected_columns)
```

This is in my opinion the most "talking" code to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 2):

Use data tables.

```
library(data.table)
long_data_table_name = data.table(long_data_frame_name, key="col1,col2,col3")
selected <- long_data_table_name[col1 == "condition1" & 
                                 col2 == "condition2" & 
                                 !is.na(col3),
                                 list(col4,col5,col6,col7)]
```

You don't have to set the key in the data.table(...) call, but if you have a large dataset, this will be **much** faster. Either way it will be much faster than using data frames. Finally, using `J(...)`, as below, does require a keyed data.table, but is even faster.

```
selected <- long_data_table_name[J("condition1","condition2",NA),
                                 list(col4,col5,col6,col7)]
```

Comment: `NA` values don't play nicely as data.table key columns, as such your second example will (probably) not work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities:

- `attach` which adds the variables of the data.frame to the search path just below the global environment. Very useful for code demonstrations but I warn you not to do that programmatically.
- `with` which creates a whole new environment temporarilly.

In very limited cases you want to use other options such as `within`.

```
df = data.frame(random=runif(100))
df1 = with(df,log(random))
df2 = within(df,logRandom <- log(random))
```

`within` will examine the created environment after evaluation and add the modifications to the data. Check the help of `with` to see more examples. `with` will just evaluate you expression.

Comment: Could you give some examples of `with`and `within`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what the benefit of using with/within is compared to simple subsetting?

Comment: Sure. Well it really depends what is the code for. Check out this other question in SO [subsettingProgrammatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850141/programming-safe-version-of-subset-to-evaluate-its-condition-while-called-from)