# List all column except for one in R

Tags: r, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drop Columns R Data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame)

Let's say I have a dataframe with column c1, c2, c3.

I want to list just c1 and c2. How do I do that?

I've tried:

```
head(data[column!="c3"])
head(data)[,2]
head(data[!"c3"])
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can index and use a negative sign to drop the 3rd column:

```
data[,-3]
```

Or you can list only the first 2 columns:

```
data[,c("c1", "c2")]
data[,1:2]
```

Don't forget the comma and referencing data frames works like this: `data[row,column]`

Comment: Regarding to your last sentence, you don't actually need the comma when working with data frames, since they are lists.

Comment: Sure, but if you're going to make that comment at least show an example of how not to use a comma aka accessing lists.

Comment: for example `x[1,2]` = `x[[2]][[1]]`

Answer (score 156):

If you are looking for negative indexing by name (in addition to [tcash21's numeric indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12868602/6409572)), here's a few ways I know, some riskier than others:

```
mtcars[, -which(names(mtcars) == "carb")]  #only works on a single column
mtcars[, names(mtcars) != "carb"]          #only works on a single column
mtcars[, !names(mtcars) %in% c("carb", "mpg")] 
mtcars[, -match(c("carb", "mpg"), names(mtcars))] 
mtcars2 <- mtcars; mtcars2$hp <- NULL         #lost column (risky)


library(gdata) 
remove.vars(mtcars2, names=c("mpg", "carb"), info=TRUE)
```

Generally I use:

```
mtcars[, !names(mtcars) %in% c("carb", "mpg")]
```

because I feel it's safe and efficient.

Comment: And see http://markmail.org/message/sdg7mopk4towqbm4 for Brian Ripley's comment on mtcars[,-c("carb","mpg")]