# Drop a list of columns from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drop Columns R Data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame)

I have a list of variables I would like to drop from IRIS table as follow:

```
dropList <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
```

How I can use this list to drop from IRIS data frame? (I don't want to refer to positions explicitly)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There's some other ways you can do this, like using the `select` argument of `subset`, but if `dropList` is coming to you as a character vector from somewhere else, this works pretty well.

```
data(iris)
dropList <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
iris2 <- iris[, !colnames(iris) %in% dropList]
```

Comment: You don't actually need `data(iris)` - it's loaded lazily for you

Comment: Thank you so much. It saves me so much time