# How to delete a column in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drop Columns R Data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame)

Suppose, I have the following dataframe, and want to delete column "dataB" what would be R command for that?

```
y <- data.frame(k1=c(101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108),
                B=c(11,12,13,NA,NA,16,17,18), 
                dataB=11:18)
```

Comment: Let's not start overusing the word "exact". This question can be answered by reading the material in that post.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This: `y$B <- NULL` removes column `B` from dataframe `y`.

Comment: See the duplicate question, linked by @mnel above.