# Attempting to drop numerous columns in R

Tags: r

I have a list of column names in an excel file (sds.drop.csv) that I want to drop from a dataframe already imported into R.

I attempted to read the column names into R as follows

```
sds.drop <- as.list(read.csv("sds.drop.csv", header = F))
```

With the intention of then running the code below to drop them from the dataframe called 'dat'

```
dat1 <-  dat[, !(names(dat) %in% sds.drop)]
```

However, no columns are dropped. I'm guessing the issue resides in the way I am reading in the data. I attempted to read the data in without the as.list() command and it still did not work. Any thoughts?

Here is what the sds.drop.csv df looks like...

```
> head(read.csv("sds.drop.csv", header = F))
   V1
1 Q20
2 Q23
3 Q24
4 Q25
5 Q26
6 Q27
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `sds.drop <- unlist(read.csv("sds.drop.csv", header = F)); dat1 <- dat[,!names(dat) %in% sds.drop]`?

Comment: @Roland That still doesn't work, and my df is a factor. I think the solution is to put " " on both sides of each value in the sds.drop df. Do you know how to add those to each variable? paste( ) ?

Comment: did you mean `dat1 <- dat[,!names(dat) %in% sds.drop]`? (I suspect `!names(sds.drop) %in% sds.drop` is not the selection  you want). Also, hard to tell if anything is wrong with the format of sds.drop without knowing anything about it.  can you add `head(read.csv("sds.drop.csv", header = F))` to your post?`

Comment: @Jthorpe correct, good catch. I fixed that but it still didn't drop the columns. I added the output from `head(read.csv("sds.drop.csv", header = F))`... it is a factor with 191 levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you're not dereferencing (i.e. extracting) the column of column names from the data.frame that is returned by `read.csv()`. It also makes sense to coerce to character, since that's what you need to operate on. Thus, you should be assigning `sds.drop` from `as.character(read.csv('sds.drop.csv',header=F)[,1]);`:

```
dat <- data.frame(Q20=1:3, Q23=4:6, Q24=7:9, Q25=10:12, Q26=13:15, Q27=16:18, Q30=19:21, Q31=22:24 );
dat;
##   Q20 Q23 Q24 Q25 Q26 Q27 Q30 Q31
## 1   1   4   7  10  13  16  19  22
## 2   2   5   8  11  14  17  20  23
## 3   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24
sds.drop <- as.character(read.csv('sds.drop.csv',header=F)[,1]);
sds.drop;
## [1] "Q20" "Q23" "Q24" "Q25" "Q26" "Q27"
dat[,!names(dat)%in%sds.drop];
##   Q30 Q31
## 1  19  22
## 2  20  23
## 3  21  24
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you, @bgoldst. I tried the as.character( ) command before, but the letters in my dataframe dropped. I think this was remedied by the `[,1]`... can you please explain what that means?

Comment: Sure. `[,1]` is a form of indexing which basically says "all rows, column 1". The `read.csv()` function returns a data.frame (which is a table of data) with one row per data line and one column per delimited field from the CSV file, so prior to indexing, you didn't actually have a list of strings, you had a table of data. Running `as.character()` on a data.frame doesn't really make sense, in fact I can't explain the output I'm getting (`"1:6"`). But by indexing column 1, you get a vector of the column data, which can be coerced to a character vector (from a factor).

Comment: Actually, instead of calling `as.character()`, you could use the `stringsAsFactors` argument of `read.table()` by setting it to false. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #keep only the headers from the csv
    cols = colnames(read.csv('C:/myfile.csv',colClasses='character',nrows =    1,header=TRUE)[-1, ])

    #subset dataframe excluding colnames in cols
    df2 <- yourdataframe[!names(yourdataframe) %in% cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# for example (you are reading this in from Excel)
dat <- data.frame("goodcol" = c(1,2), "badcol1"= c(-1,-2),
                  "badcol2"= c(-2,-4), "goodcol2" = c(2,4))

sds.drop <- c("badcol1", "badcol2")

dat <-  dat[, !(names(dat) %in% sds.drop)]
```

You may have been missing a bracket and needed to refer to the dateframe in `names()`.

EDIT For those who later search - Similar to 
[Drop data frame columns by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-r-data-frame)

Comment: Thanks @micstr, but still doesn't work. I fixed the code and added the brackets around names, but to no avail.

Comment: This is not a precedence issue; `%any%` special operators have higher precedence than negation (`!`). See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html.

Comment: Just check your sds.drop type is not numeric but a list? Will try check your data later.