# Dropping unary variables in R

Tags: r

I would like to understand how I can drop variables from a data frame in R if they are unary, that contains only one value. I sometimes have data frames with thousands of variables, and one of my first steps would be to get rid of those variables (which often is handed over to me from a data warehouse).

I understand that I can drop columns like

```
drops <- c("x","z")
DF[,!(names(DF) %in% drops)]
```

as outlined here:
[Drop data frame columns by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-columns-in-r-data-frame)

But I would like some way of searching through all the variables, and dropping unary only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should identify a "nonunary" variable according to your definition:

```
nonunary <- function(x) length(unique(x))>1
```

And this should filter the variables in a data frame accordingly:

```
DF[sapply(DF,nonunary)]
```