# Rename CSV's based on column name

Tags: r, csv

I tried joining csv files present in two directories in R, having same name.
For example 1.csv and 2.csv are present in /path/directory1 and /path/directory2.
I joined the two files(1.csv with 1.csv). As given in below code:

```
directories <- c("/path/directory1", "/path/directory2")
files <- lapply(directories, list.files, pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
files <- lapply(files, sort)
joined <- Map(function(x,y) { join(read.csv(x), read.csv(y), by=c("date")) },
           files[[1]], files[[2]])
```

Now, "joined" contains the list of csv’s. Now I want to store all the csv’s
in directory (say “path/directory3”) but the csv name should be based on column
For example,
Every csv contains information about each country. There is “country” column: values are Australia, New Zealand, India, United States.

So, csv name should be **Australia.csv**, **New Zealand.csv** and so on.

Please help! 
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I guess you'd be better of with some unix based solution, like `awk '{print $0 >> $1.tsv}'`, [docs here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html).

Comment: Yes correct, but I want  to do this in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
lapply(joined, function(x) write.csv(x, file = paste0(x[["country"]][1], ".csv")))
```

Obviously, add the relevant arguments you're interested in for `write.csv` as required.

To get the file name, we select just the "country" column (`x[["country"]]`) and then just the first value in that column (`[1]`) since we only need one value to create a file name.

Comment: Thanks!!! one more query, if we want to remove same columns from the list of data frames. And then write it to the csv's. Could you tell this also?

Comment: @Kaushik, do they all have the same name? If so, instead of `write.csv(x,...)`, you could use one of the approaches [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name) to subset `x` before writing it to a csv file.