# Creating new column using ["newColName"] versus $newColName

Tags: r

To create a new column in data :

```
library("titanic")
traint <- titanic_train
```

I use :

```
traint["newCol"] <- traint['Survived'] == 1
```

or

```
traint$newCol <- traint['Survived'] == 1
```

The newly created column added to `traint` data appear equivalent.

Which method should I choose when creating a new column within data ?  `["newColName"]` or `$newColName` ? Are both methods of creating the new column equivalent ?

Comment: You can also use `[[<-`: `traint[["newCol"]] <- traint[['Survived']] == 1`. I'd recommend you read (and reread) `?Extract` and `?"[.data.frame"`. These are the answers you seek.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name) may also provide some perspectives.

Comment: I removed the rstudio tag as this should only be used for questions that involve the IDE. This question is about standard R.

Comment: The way you use `[ ` and `$` in your example, there is no difference (or at least none that matters). If, however, the name of the column to be created is stored in a variable, you can not use `$`.