# Drop Columns of Another Dataframe from Main Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes,

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,9), b = c(1,2,3,4,5) , c = c(1,2,3,4,9), d = c(1,2,3,4,5) )

df2 <- data.frame( c = c(1,2,3,4,5) ,a = c(1,2,3,4,5) )
```

I want to drop all column names of df2 from df1

Something like that below (but not working)

```
df1[, -colnames(df2)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop data frame columns by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name)

Answer (score 1):

using `%in%` can do the job:

```
df1 <- df1[, !colnames(df1) %in% colnames(df2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` solution. The `select` function from `dplyr` allows you to select or omit columns by name or index number. You can use the `-` operator to omit.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(magrittr)
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,9), b = c(1,2,3,4,5) , c = c(1,2,3,4,9), d = c(1,2,3,4,5) )
df2 <- data.frame( c = c(1,2,3,4,5) ,a = c(1,2,3,4,5) )
df1 %<>% select(-colnames(df2))
```