# removing columns from a data frame

Tags: r

I have read in an excel file which is now called salaries_raw.
There are some columns that are not required.

```
'''{r}
  not_required <- names(salaries_raw)[c(1,2,3,4,6,11,19,20,21,22)]
'''
```

how do I remove these specific rows from my dat frame?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop data frame columns by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name)

Comment: yes thank you, didn't see this question